# Mac Air trackpad suddenly doesn't respond

Tags: laptop, freeze, mac, trackpad

When the trackpad stops responding, this leaves me unable to do anything, including shutting down.  Is there a fix?

Comment: There are many reasons your trackpad might not work.  can you give more details, such as what you were doing when it stops and how often this seems to happen?  Please also state the version of Ubuntu and MacBook Air you are using.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Known problem, after updating and rebooting the problem usually gets fixed. Here are instructions on how to do all that using the keyboard.

1. Press `CTRL+ALT+T`. This should bring up a terminal.
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
4. `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Apple Magic Trackpad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchUSBID      "05ac:030e"
    Driver          "synaptics"
    Option          "VertScrollDelta"  "50"
    Option          "HorizScrollDelta" "50"
    Option          "MinSpeed"         "0.6"
    Option          "MaxSpeed"         "1.3"
    Option          "AccelFactor"      "0.08"
    # these two options are for multiple monitors 3:1 ratio.
    Option          "VertResolution"   "1"
    Option          "HorizResolution"  "3"
    Option          "SHMConfig"        "True"
EndSection
```

/etc/init.d/lightdm restart